# I want to align the text in the list box from right to left In AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a list box, but I want to make the text written in it right to left, in the following code, in order to write the text in Arabic starting from right to left. Please help us solve this problem

```
stop();
import fl.controls.List;

var list:List = new List();
list.setSize(167,300);
list.move(788,165);
list.addItem({label:"Track 1"});
list.addItem({label:"Track 2"});
list.addItem({label:"Track 3"});
list.addItem({label:"Track 4"});
list.addItem({label:"Track 5"});
list.addItem({label:"Track 6"});

addChild(list);
```

Comment: You need to use a custom cell renderer that is designed with a **TextField** able to display right-to-left texts. Scroll down for the example: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/CellRenderer.html

Comment: I am working on preparing educational programs for high school, but I am not good at programming, so it is difficult for me to benefit from the explanation in the previous link. I hope you will modify the code that I sent, so that it is ready, so that the text becomes from right to left.
Thank you for your cooperation

Comment: As much as I sympathize with your case, there's no **simple** solution for your problem. It's not like there are a couple of lines that can be added you your existing code and *magically* make it works. The minimal amount of trouble here is figuring how to make right-to-left texts at all, then designing a **CellRenderer** wrapper class that introduces it to the **List**. So, good luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the code that is used for alignment and other formatting of text in a cell.
Thank you for cooperation in solving our problems.

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.font = "Arial";
tf.color = 0x000000;
tf.size = 18;
tf.italic = true;
tf.bold = true;
tf.underline = true;
tf.align = "right";
list.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf);
```